# Half shown div slides up on hover

Tags: html, css

Currently, I copy this code that shows a hidden div on hover

[example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_slidebottom)

but what I want is something like this

[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5a4y.png)

What I want is when you hover on title on the 1st box, shown on the 2nd picture, the div containing the title will slide up and occupy the whole space, revealing the other contents below the title.

Can someone recommend me a tutorial similar to this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried so far with your example? Have you tried to modified it a bit? Post your code here so we can help you.

Comment: On top of what @threeFatCat said, try to explain more about the expected behavior. By only looking at the image, it is not clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry I'm really bad at css so I didn't try that much to modify it. What I want is when you hover on title, the div containing the title will slide up and occupy the whole space, revealing the other contents below the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* try this */

```
.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 }

 .image {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 }

 .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  }

  .container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
   }
   .container .text2{
   display:none;
    }
    .container:hover .text2{
    display:block;
   padding-top:30px;
     }

    .text {
      color: white;
       font-size: 20px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       text-align: center;
    }
```

```
  <h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
   <p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

   <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World

    <div class="text2"> content 1</div>
    </div>
     </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Yes This is it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the height percentage of the overlay box like so..

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```